# Offset when reading binary file in python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have an [OSM PBF file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) which I am trying to parse. The format standard states, and reading it in Sublime Text this is confirmed, that the first four bytes are:

`0000 000d`

Why then, if I run a very simple Python program:

```
PBFfile = open(r'MyFilePath.osm.pbf')
PBFfile.read(4)[3].encode('hex')
```

does it return `0a` (the next byte in the sequence) not the expected `0d`? Is there an obvious explanation?

I am on Windows 7, Python 2.7.5 32 bit.

Comment: On Windows '\r' is stripped from text file records.  Open the file in binary mode `open(filename, 'rb')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening the file in "text mode", which causes some unwanted newline handling ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)).

To solve your problem, open it in binary mode, like:

```
PBFfile = open(r'MyFilePath.osm.pbf', 'rb')
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. I never realised it was so important. Guess it's a Windows thing :(